# Deepstreamhub problems with creating apps

Tags: deepstream.io

I've been unable to create new apps (or signup for a new ones) on deepstreamhub.com
There are no responses on their slack channel and no responses from support.

Are anyone out there running serious production systems of deepstreamhub (the hosted solution) or deepstream.io (the open source server)

We are trying to implement it but runs in the lots of little problems like this.

The software is a fantastic concept, and it works great (most of the time).
The open source server (deepstream.io) for self hosting is very important to our usage. But if the service for signup is this non-existent, it makes me worry.

Answer (score 2):

Deyan, thanks for your answer and the continuous presence of ably around our ecosystem. As hinted at deepstreamHub - the hosted platform - will be discontinued to allow us to fully focus on the enterprise versions as well as open source - with deepstream v4 on the very near horizon.