# Where to get "'<YOUR APP URL>'" from deepstream

Tags: deepstream.io

All:

I am trying to follow the tutorial on [deepstreamhub](https://deepstreamhub.com/tutorials/getting-started/vuejs/)

there is one section talking about how to add deepstream in,

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        ds: null,
    },
    created: function() {
        this.ds = deepstream('<YOUR APP URL>')
        .login()
    }
})
```

I wonder How can I get my `"<YOUR APP URL>"`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer is useful at the moment or not, but as per the news from January 2018, deepstreamhub platform was shutdown and not up and running, hence you are unable to register/signup for an account.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48490587/6867321) is the answer from one of the founders of deepstreamhub which you might want to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your app url should be an ip on which you run deepstream server. For example if you use it locally it can be;

this.ds = deepstream('localhost:6020')

6020 is the default port